# How to motorize a LEGO Pneumatic valve?

Tags: technic, design, pneumatic

I am working on a project that requires remotely switched LEGO valves, and I tried many designs I found, and none of them worked due to the valve causing too much resistance. Does anyone have a remotely switched valve design that fulfills the conditions below?

1. It must be tested and work.
2. It must use only PF motors.
3. It must not use [32449](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32449#T=C).

Comment: Why the ban on 32449 (thin liftarm length 4) ?

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve Because I do not have it and don't want to wait for one to be shipped.

Comment: I just think that your question would be more relevant to others without this restriction, see point 4 of https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, even if a presented design contained the forbidden element, you surely can replace it with an alternative element ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried many designs I found

A quick Google search resulted in the following designs. Have you tried them all?

[Sariel's Autovalve](http://sariel.pl/2008/12/pneumatic-autovalve/):[image]

[Philo's pneumatic valve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaBe3SZ3FEA):

[image]

[Sariel's Servo Valve](http://sariel.pl/2016/06/liebherr-r974-pneumatic-excavator/):[image]

[Tamas Juhasz's small autovalve with compressor](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/87307-small-autovalve/):[image]

[Technic-Dragon's Compact Pneumatic Autovalve](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-4730/Technic-Dragon/lego-technic-compact-pneumatic-autovalve/):[image]

---

Bonus entries, not using exclusively PF motors, but could be adapted to:

[Conchas' Micromotor valve](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=299371):

[image]

[Pneumatically controlled valve from the B model of 8868-1: Air Tech Claw Rig](https://brickset.com/sets/8868-1/Air-Tech-Claw-Rig)[image]

Comment: I have my doubts about a couple of these designs. When under pressure, the valve switch takes quite a bit of force to turn. I think a couple of these designs don't have sufficient gearing down to work unless there's no significant pressure yet.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve I haven't tried any of them personally (except for the 8868), but provided links to their respective websites and forum threads, where comments might be left to indicate such problems and their solutions.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve The first Sariel autovalve is not super reliable - in my experience, the small liftarms can get stuck in certain positions. The servo valves definitely have more than enough torque. The micromotor valve is definitely questionable, not to mention that it requires a sensor and probably takes 5-10 seconds to flip state. Pneumatic autovalves are pretty common in air-powered creations.